# Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version

Tags: java, neo4j

I have started with my neo4j basics... 
My neo4j  asks for a newer version while mine is the latest, do i have to correct anything in my code(here it follows) or  anything to install or update.

**In the code newEmbeddedDatabase is deprecated i dont know how to rectify..

** While i am starting my neo4j server it shows an Alert message
"Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter "allow_store_upgrade=true"  "

** I enabled allow_store_upgrade=true and am using neo4j 2.3.2
Please Help me
Thanks in advance

```
package neo4j;
public class neo4j_demo {
public static void main(String[] args) 
  {

   GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory =new GraphDatabaseFactory();

        GraphDatabaseService db= dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("C:/TPNeo4jDB");
        try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {

            Node javaNode = db.createNode(Tutorials.JAVA);
            javaNode.setProperty("TutorialID", "JAVA001");
            javaNode.setProperty("Title", "Learn Java");
            javaNode.setProperty("NoOfChapters", "25");
            javaNode.setProperty("Status", "Completed");                

            Node scalaNode = db.createNode(Tutorials.SCALA);
            scalaNode.setProperty("TutorialID", "SCALA001");
            scalaNode.setProperty("Title", "Learn Scala");
            scalaNode.setProperty("NoOfChapters", "20");
            scalaNode.setProperty("Status", "Completed");

            Relationship relationship = javaNode.createRelationshipTo
            (scalaNode,TutorialRelationships.JVM_LANGIAGES);
            relationship.setProperty("Id","1234");
            relationship.setProperty("OOPS","YES");
            relationship.setProperty("FP","YES");

            tx.success();
        }
           System.out.println("Done successfully");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your maven dependency? You might want to replace your maven entry with this.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
<artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
<version>2.X.X</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Where it s located? Thanx for response